# Comparing a parameter pack? Expansion syntax?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <utility>

class foo 
{
private:
    struct s 
    {
        int value;
        s* p2;
    } *p;
public:
    foo() : p(new s{ 0, nullptr }) {}

    template<class... Args>
    void fun(Args&&... val) 
    {
        if (val > p->value) //point of interest
            p->p2 = new s{ { std::forward<Args>(val)... }, nullptr };
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo o;
    o.fun(34);
}
```

How would I get `val > p->value` to work? I tried things like `val... > p->value` and `{ val... } > p->value`, but I can't seem to get the right syntax. Thanks!

Comment: What is that supposed to do (i.e., what do you want the condition to actually be)?

Comment: Perhaps you were going for a condition of all values being greater, or maybe any value being greater? I.e., the equivalent of C++17 `((val > p->value) && ...)` or `((val > p->value) || ...)` However, you can't turn a parameter pack into `new s{{val1, new s{{val2, new s{{val3, ...}}}}}}` if that's what you were going for.

Comment: One thing to consider is that it's easy to construct a `std::list` from a parameter pack of the same type. `std::list<T>{std::forward<Args>(vals)...}`. This is because it has a list constructor that initializes the list via regular iteration through that initializer list. Perhaps you can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I get `val > p->value` to work?

One option is to use a much simpler function:

```
void fun(int val) 
{
    if (val > p->value)
        p->p2 = new s{ val, nullptr };
}
```

Comment: Actually, good point. That initializer is always ill-formed unless `val` has either one or no element.

Comment: @T.C., are you talking about the initializer for `new s{...};`?

Comment: I'm talking about the `{ std::forward<Args>(val)... }` part in OP's code.